# How to Hide products with particular attribute value through out the site?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute, product-collection

I want to hide products, which don't have value of a particular attribute, from every page of my website. for this  I have used observer on event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` and `catalog_product_load_after` and here is my observer function:

```
public function customFilter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller', array('neq' => 'NULL'));

    return $collection;
}
```

If I print the sql query and run it into my database it returns proper results. But the filter applied here does not reflect in frontend.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the wrong event you observe. In this place the collection is already loaded.

Replace:

```
catalog_product_collection_load_after
```

With:

```
catalog_product_collection_load_before
```

Comment: May be you are correct,  question is old so can't check with your answer now . +1 for your efforts.

Comment: If tested it recently ... it works ;) I'd be nice if you can reproduce this to close this question :)

Comment: I will surely try this :)